# Using both mod_php(Apache) and php-fpm(nginx) in one server

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php-fpm, mod-php

Is it possible to use `Apache+mod_php` and `nginx+php-fpm` in same server?
I know these two servers can NOT share same port, but is it possible to run two different PHP modules in one server?

I'm planning to use some website with Apache and some with nginx (for performance testing).

Both is installed via `YUM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are asking is the possibility, then yes, each has it's own port/sock file that it's listening to so there's no conflict.

You can set nginx as main and make it proxy to apache whatever domains you want to proxy to apahce.